# Toggle DIV visibility based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm still finding my way around Javascript at the moment, so apologies if I'm missing something really obvious with this (likely!).

I have a small form with a number of radio buttons, like so;

```
<input type="radio" name="dtype" id="dtype" value="option1">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" id="dtype" value="option2">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" id="dtype" value="option3">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" id="dtype" value="option4">
```

Based on the user's selection, I need to immediately show the relevant div.  I have this working fine for the first radio, but not for any subsequent ones (and no errors reported in firebug).  This is what I have right now;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#dtype').change(function() {
if($(this).val() == 'option1') {$('#div1').slideToggle('500');}
if($(this).val() == 'option2') {$('#div2').slideToggle('500');} 
if($(this).val() == 'option3') {$('#div3').slideToggle('500');}
if($(this).val() == 'option4') {$('#div4').slideToggle('500');}
});
});
</script>
```

I also tried 'else if' on the 3 after the first, without success. Pointers welcome!

Comment: You will receive better results if you create a demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to select all of your input elements using the same ID (**[ID's should be unique](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm)**). You could try changing your ID `#dtype` to a class `.dtype`, and select them via. class instead.

Here's a working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp5Fq/)** in regard to your use-case.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="dtype" class="dtype" value="option1">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" class="dtype" value="option2">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" class="dtype" value="option3">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" class="dtype" value="option4">

<div id="div1">A</div>
<div id="div2">B</div>
<div id="div3">C</div>
<div id="div4">D</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  $('.dtype').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'option1') {$('#div1').slideToggle('500');}
    if($(this).val() == 'option2') {$('#div2').slideToggle('500');} 
    if($(this).val() == 'option3') {$('#div3').slideToggle('500');}
    if($(this).val() == 'option4') {$('#div4').slideToggle('500');}
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly, and I've learnt something new!

Answer (score 0):

Ids need to be unique, you therefore have to do this:

```
<input type="radio" name="dtype" id="dtype1" value="option1">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" id="dtype2" value="option2">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" id="dtype3" value="option3">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" id="dtype4" value="option4">
```

And the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('input[name=dtype]').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'option1') {$('#div1').slideToggle('500');}
    if($(this).val() == 'option2') {$('#div2').slideToggle('500');} 
    if($(this).val() == 'option3') {$('#div3').slideToggle('500');}
    if($(this).val() == 'option4') {$('#div4').slideToggle('500');}
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with ID you have same ID's for all radio buttons - change id to class so it will look like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="radio" name="dtype" class="dtype" value="option1">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" class="dtype" value="option2">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" class="dtype" value="option3">
<input type="radio" name="dtype" class="dtype" value="option4">

<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.dtype').change(function() {
alert($(this).val());
if($(this).val() == 'option1') {$('#div1').slideToggle('500');}
else if($(this).val() == 'option2') {$('#div2').slideToggle('500');} 
else if($(this).val() == 'option3') {$('#div3').slideToggle('500');}
else if($(this).val() == 'option4') {$('#div4').slideToggle('500');}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: @user125697 ofcourse! I started writing this when there were no comments - I guess i`m a slow writer

Comment: Thanks to all that took the time to answer - I can only accept one as the answer unfortunately, although you all answered correctly.

Comment: @user125697 Can't write them different anyways 'cause of given $('#div1'). $('#div2'). ... ;) it's all good!